# How to disable sticky selection in polymer core-menu

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

This issue was raised in the Github repo on 9 Sept 2014:

```
Whenever I select a menu item, and the menu disappears, the next time 
I open the menu, my previous selection remains selected. This makes it 
impossible to reselect the same menu item.
```

There is an implemented solution (19 Sept) in a comment under core-menu-button:

```
There is now a stickySelection property that defaults to false.
```

Since it defaults to false, I should never need to set it. But the sticky behavior persists and I cannot work out where to set the attribute/property. Here is the menu:

```
  <core-menu-button>
    <core-icon-button icon='more-vert'></core-icon-button>
    <core-dropdown class='dropdown'>
      <core-menu on-core-select='{{menuSelectHandler}}'>
        <template repeat='{{menuItems}}'>
          <core-item label='{{}}'></core-item>
        </template>
      </core-menu>
    </core-dropdown>
  </core-menu-button>
```

In between menu selections I would like to return the menu to "nothing selected."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `stickySelection` property was removed when the `core-menu-button` was refactored. I'm not sure if this was done on purpose, so I've reopened the original bug.

As a workaround in the meantime, you can listen for the on-core-overlay-open event (fired when the menu overlay opens or closes) and clear the selection manually. In the markup, add the event listener and give the menu an ID:

```
<core-menu-button on-core-overlay-open="{{menuOpen}}">
  <core-icon-button icon='menu'></core-icon-button>
  <core-dropdown class='dropdown'>
    <core-menu id="menu" on-core-select='{{menuSelectHandler}}'>
```

The `menuOpen` method would look like this:

```
    menuOpen: function(e) {
      if (! e.detail.opened) {
        this.$.menu.selected = null;
      }
    }
```

(Alternately, you could listen on `core-overlay-close-completed`, which is fired when the overlay finishes closing. I was afraid that would lead to timing issues if the user closed and reopened the menu rapidly, but it doesn't appear to be an issue on core-menu-button, perhaps because there's no delay closing the menu.)

Comment: Thanks. From other answers on S.O. I'm OK with "e.detail.opened", but any hints on converting "this.$.menu.selected" into Dart?

Comment: Hm... I don't know Dart, but it looks like you still have the `$` hash, but since it's a Dart Map instead of a plain JavaScript object, you need to access it using bracket syntax. So `this.$.menu` should be `this.$['menu']`. See: https://github.com/dart-lang/polymer-dart-patterns/tree/master/web/basics/finding_shadow_dom_elements

Comment: Back on this after a gap.. $['menu'].selected = null doesn't work. It needs some more js-interop mojo. Any ideas or should I post a new question?

Comment: OK. Fix the **menuSelectHandler** to clear the **selected** var like this `  void menuSelectHandler(CustomEvent e, JsObject detail) {
    if (detail['isSelected']) { $['menu'].selected = -1;...}`